# Möbius strip unit normal

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation

[image]
Why is $\lambda(\theta)$ $+or-1$? Won’t the unit normal be pointing in various directions as the point moves along $\theta?$. Also what does it mean for unit normal to vary smoothly over $S$?

Comment: What is $N_\sigma$?

Comment: It is the standard unit normal of the surface patch $\sigma$

Comment: Then how can $N$ be anything but $\pm N_\sigma$?  There are only two unit normals at a point.  BTW, when he says that $N$ varies smoothly over $S$, he means $N$ is a continuous function defined on $S$.